# Type mismatch in variable assignment to generics based variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Does anyone know why C# doesn't seem to like the following bit of code?

The issue is that `MyContext` cannot be assigned to the `_context` variable due to its type mismatch, however `MyContext` derives (inherits?) from `DbContext`, so that should satisfy the generics where clause, surely?

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    private TContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new MyContext(Common.ConfigurationProvider.DatabaseConnectionString);
    }
...

}
```

Comment: You can't say `class C<T> where T : Animal { T animal = new Giraffe(); }` because then `C<Tiger>` has a field of type `Tiger` that contains a `Giraffe`! Either eliminate the generic: `class U { private DbContext c; public U() { c = new MyContext(); }}` or make the field of the exact type `class U<T> { MyContext c; }` or have the context passed in `class U<T> where T : C { T c; public U(T c) { this.c = c; } }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed because `where TContext : DbContext` constraint promises that `TContext` will be of `DbContext` and not `MyContext`.

In other words `TContext` may be `MyContext2` which have no inheritance relationship with `MyContext`. So compiler is not happy with that :(

If you're going to use specific context `MyContext` then IMO you don't need generics.

---

Edit: If you're sure that your context will be descendant of type argument(TContext) then you can play a trick to make it work,

```
public UnitOfWork()
{
    _context = (TContext)(object)new MyContext(...);
}
```

but, I will think twice before using this in production code. This will fail if `MyContext` is not `TContext` or descendant of it.

Comment: Bah, humbug - so is there any way to genericise something like this, where DbContext is a class that is derived from and not an interface?  I've found myself in a situation where I need multiple EF contexts for multiple schemas (Im accessing several different databases) and while my generic repositories work well with one context, I now either need them to work with multiple contexts or I will be duplicating code all over the place...

Comment: I will point out that my example above is just an example - the creation of the context in the example is not production code, it just skips the requirement to show you other code :)  So ideally the context creation would be done via other means, not the means shown.

Comment: So will you be sure that you always create a context which is definitely of type `TContext` or descendant of that?

Comment: It will always be derived from DbContext, but may be different actual context implementations, so it might not be the same TContext in every use.

Answer (score 0):

`TContext` could be another type inheriting from `DbContext` incompatible with the type of `MyContext`.